# how to render viewport in 2.9?

Tags: rendering

How do I render the viewport in 2.9?  There seems to be no option in the menu for it other than render image as fully rendered.  I could do it in earlier versions, has it been removed as an option?  Or is it in another place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in the 3d Viewport under "View":

[image: ViewRend]